# Spring Cloud Starter config unknown error during POM dependency check

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-cloud-config

I am seeing the following error when adding a dependency for my config client. Also I'm not able to add @RefreshScope annotation since its not able to find the package.

[image: Dependency Error]

[image: Package Error]

But the contents are present in my local repository with version 1.4.2.

Just starting off with spring-boot and hence not sure on next steps.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>customer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>customer</name>
  <description>Project with local MongoDB</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general typing out the text, or copying it, is better than a screenshot because it is text searchable.

Comment: sure,  will do that. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Could you please also attach your pom.xml?

Comment: thanks again for the feedback. Updated the post

Answer (score 3):

The Spring Boot Parent does not manage any dependencies for Spring Cloud.

Spring Cloud builds on Spring Boot.

> Spring Cloud builds on Spring Boot by providing a bunch of libraries that enhance the behaviour of an application when added to the classpath. You can take advantage of the basic default behaviour to get started really quickly, and then when you need to, you can configure or extend to create a custom solution.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/

There is multiple "release trains" that are effectively tied, or contain differing versions of dependencies, to Spring Boot.

You will want to add a dependencyManagement section to manage the Spring Cloud dependencies

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Edgware.SR2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

`Edgware.SR2` is the latest release train for the Spring Boot 1.5.X family. You could also use the Dalston Release train, I believe the only difference being that Edgware contain's some breaking changes.